Принудительное завершение потоков
У меня асинхронное приложение, которое парсит данные каждые N минут и записывает их в БД. Вместе с этим консоль принимает команды от пользователя (на вывод или экспорт данных в xlsx) - всё независимо друг от друга.
При ручном завершении скрипта иногда вылетают ошибки, типа:
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1537, in _shutdown
    atexit_call()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 31, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1096, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1116, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt: 
^C

У меня есть такое:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nВыполнение прервано пользователем.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\nОшибка: {e}")

Оно исключает всё, кроме threading. В приложении я использую только asyncio.
В main запускается парсинг каждые N минут и консоль для ввода команд:
async def main():
    # Запуск обновления данных отдельном таске
    asyncio.create_task(update_data(a, b, c))
    # Запуск интерфейса пользователя
    await ui.run()

В update_data и методе интерфейса ui.run есть бесконечные циклы:
async def update_data(a, b, c):
    while True:
        # Ждем delay минут перед следующим обновлением
        await asyncio.sleep(delay * 60)
        try:
            
....................

async def run(self):
    # метод принимает команды от пользователя
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, input)
            if cmd in self.command_dict:
                await self.command_dict[cmd]()
                continue
            else:
                print(self.help_message)
        except EOFError:
            break

Как принудительно завершить потоки или завершить их корректно? Ошибки не всегда появляются, думаю, это связанно с бесконечными циклами...

Попробуйте asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()) вместо asyncio.run(main())

@CrazyElf не помогло. Видимо надо добавлять какой-то флаг для завершения бесконечных циклов

Ок, попробуйте заканселить таски как вот здесь пишут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766124/8324991 Но для этого их придётся собрать как-то, а не отпускать в свободное плавание. Так а except KeyboardInterrupt: вообще не срабатывает или это помимо него выпадает ещё диагностика?

Я бы в обработчике KeyboardInterrupt сделал бы отправку стоп-ивента который уже в потоках бы обработал. И осталось бы только дождаться пока все потоки закроются.

@CrazyElf KeyboardInterrupt у меня в except, там вылетает стандартная ошибка или предупреждение, что приложение закончилось, но except ее скрывает. А ошибка в посте как-то рандомно появляется с разными кодами /usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py

@Amgarak честно говоря, не понял о чём Вы

Решение нашлось само - не знаю как это работает.
В общем логика приложения была такая: при запуске делает парсинг, результат пишется в БД. Потом запускается main происходит парсинг с записью в БД: asyncio.create_task(update_data(a, b, c)) и запускается интерфейс await ui.run()
Затем в update_data ставится таймер await asyncio.sleep(delay * 60) и потом происходит основная логика обновления.
Что я сделал: убрал парсинг и запись из main, а таймер перенёс в конец update_data. Т.е. я убрал лишний (повторяющийся) код, особо не ломая изначальную логику.
Ошибки с процессами больше не появляются.
